# How to set checkAll for in angularjs ng-repeat table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a complex ng-repeat table,which I need to set the select all function for the checkbox of each row.He is my code:
JS:

```
  $scope.getCCGenie = function(){
                CCGenieService.transactionList().then(function(list){
                    $scope.CreditCardsList = list;
                    $scope.CorporateCardsNum = $scope.CreditCardsList.transactionInfo.corpCardCount;
                    $scope.PersonalCardsNum = $scope.CreditCardsList.transactionInfo.personalCardCount;
                });
            } 

            $scope.hasExpenseTypeLabel = false;
            $scope.getCCGenie();
             $scope.checkAllcorp = function(copcards) {
        console.log(copcards);
        if (copcards.selectedAllcorp) {
            copcards.selectedAllcorp = true;
            $scope.hasSelectedExpense = true;

        } else {
            copcards.selectedAllcorp = false;
            $scope.hasSelectedExpense = false;

        }
        angular.forEach('copcards.transactions',function(v,k){
            v.corpisSelected = copcards.selectedAllcorp;
        })
    };
          // I need to loop the selected table to reset each corpisSelected,assign them the new value selectedAllcorp. but how?
            };
Html:

    <ul>
                <li ng-repeat='copcards in CreditCardsList.transactionInfo.corporateCards'>
                <span class='creditcardsubtitle'>{{copcards.cardName}} (****{{copcards.cardNumber}})</span> 
                <table class='table col-xs-12 col-md-12  col-lg-12' border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <th class='text-center'><input type="checkbox" ng-model="copcards.selectedAllcorp" ng-change="checkAllcorp(copcards)"/></th>
                        <th class='text-left'>Date</th>
                        <th class='text-left'>Merchant</th>
                        <th class='text-right'>Amount</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Expense Type</th>
                        <th class='text-left'><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAllBill" ng-change="checkAllBillable()" style='margin-right:3px;'/>  Billable</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Attachment</th>
                        <th class='text-center'>Description</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr ng-show='noExpense'><td colspan="8"  align="center" style="text-align: center;" >No any Personal Cards!</td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat='componentObject in copcards.transactions' ng-class="{'selectedrow':componentObject.corpisSelected}">
                            <td type='checkbox' class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' ng-model='componentObject.corpisSelected' class='deletebox'/>{{componentObject.corpisSelected}}</td>
                            <td class='text-left tdwidth'>{{componentObject.transactionDateString | parseDateFormat | date}}</td>
                            <td class='text-left tdwidth'>{{componentObject.merchant}}</td>
                            <td class='text-right tdwidth'>${{componentObject.amount}}</td>
                            <td class='text-center tdwidth'><smart-expense-type></smart-expense-type></td>
                            <td class='text-left tdwidth'><input type='checkbox' ng-model='componentObject.isBillable'/></td>
                            <td class='text-center tdwidth'>{{componentObject.hasImage}}</td>
                            <td class='text-center tdwidth'><input type='text'ng-model='componentObject.description'/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

As you can see, I use nasted ng-repeat the loop data, there may be many tables over there, I want each table has his own selectAll function which works independently. Now the code is partly working fine, the problem is if you check the single checkbox in row, the checkall function will not work.I know I need to do something like this:

```
$scope.checkAllcorp = function() {
                if (this.selectedAllcorp) {
                    $scope.hasSelectedExpense = true
                    this.selectedRow = true;
                    this.corpisSelected = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.hasSelectedExpense = false;
                    this.selectedRow = false;
                    this.corpisSelected = false;
                }
          angular.forEach('selectedTable',function(v,k){
                   v.corpisSelected = this.selectedAllcorp;
})
            };
```

But how can I access this 'selectedTable'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `copcards` to your function and then operate on that object instead of `this`:

```
ng-change="checkAllcorp(copcards)"
```

And then in your controller:

```
$scope.checkAllcorp = function(copcards) {

  if (copcards.selectedAllcorp) {

    $scope.hasSelectedExpense = true
    copcards.selectedRow = true;
    copcards.corpisSelected = true;

  } else {

    $scope.hasSelectedExpense = false;
    copcards.selectedRow = false;
    copcards.corpisSelected = false;

  }

  angular.forEach('selectedTable',function(v,k){
    v.corpisSelected = copcards.selectedAllcorp;
  })
};
```

Comment: How can I update the Html? I tried but looks like doesn't work.

Comment: I just update my code, would you please check it out for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the object you are on by calling it thru the function itself like this

```
ng-change="checkAllcorp(copcards)
```

and then use it as a parameter for you checkAllcorp function instead of this in you function

example :

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names"><button ng-click="msg(name)"></button></div>
```

controller scope :

```
$scope.msg = function(name) { alert(name.first)};
```